# Add to django project an e-mail account

Tags: python, django, email

I would like to know if there is any way to add an e-mail account into a django project with all its functionalities; send, receive, bin...

And if so where can I find a tutorial or guide to develop it?

Answer (score 1):

You can send emails in Django very easily. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/) says

> Although Python makes sending email relatively easy via the smtplib module, Django provides a couple of light wrappers over it. These wrappers are provided to make sending email extra quick, to make it easy to test email sending during development, and to provide support for platforms that can’t use SMTP.

In two lines:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

You can also check this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/13/how-to-send-email.html) by  Vitor Freitas.

You also need to check https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail which integrates several transactional email service providers (ESPs) into Django, with a consistent API that lets you use ESP-added features without locking your code to a particular ESP.

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmed mentioned yet, that is the way you would send an email. The settings for sending emails are set in your **settings.py**.

For example:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@smith.de'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '1234' -- you should read the password from a file
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.server.de'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Then you can send your emails like Ahmed mentioned. Django uses the information provided in your settings.py to send emails.